# Error in official scrapy example?

Tags: python, scrapy

Tried the example scrapy usage appearing on the [documentation page](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)
(example under the name: Return multiple Requests and items from a single callback)

I just changed the domains to point to a real website:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'huffingtonpost'
    allowed_domains = ['huffingtonpost.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/politics/',
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entertainment/',
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/media/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for h3 in response.xpath('//h3').extract():
            yield {"title": h3}

        for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

But getting `ValuError` as posted in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/042fe67f66416185e023).
Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using 2.7.6

Comment: Same version here, on ubuntu 14.04.3 ... don't know what might be causing it...

Answer (score 4):

Some extracted links are relative (for example, `/news/hillary-clinton/`).
You should transform it into absolute (`http://www.huffingtonpost.com/news/hillary-clinton/`

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'huffingtonpost'
    allowed_domains = ['huffingtonpost.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/politics/',
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entertainment/',
        'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/media/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for h3 in response.xpath('//h3').extract():
            yield {"title": h3}

        for url in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
            if url.startswith('/'):
                # transform url into absolute
                url = 'http://www.huffingtonpost.com' + url
            if url.startswith('#'):
                # ignore href starts with #
                continue
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: So the official scrapy example assumes that all the links returned are absolute? (which is presumably a wrong assumption?)

Comment: response.xpath('//a/@href').extract() just extracted href value from a tag. It may be absolute or relative url, link to an element with a specified id within the page (like href="#top"), or a script (like href="javascript:alert('Hello');")

Comment: Don't disagree with what ur saying...IF that is the case however, it is not appropriate especially as an introductory example.

Comment: I don't see the example using huffingtonpost.com page.